# Raise an alert in prometheus when logstash's elasticsearch output plugin log an error

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, prometheus, logstash-configuration

I am using logtash 6.6.2 to send logs to elasticsearch. When logstash is unable to send a log record to elasticsearch , elasticsearch output plugin log an error in the logstash container. I am wondering if there is a way to raise an alert in prometheus with some metrics provide by logstash to be aknowledge to that error.
I looked at the metrics provide on the metrics endpoint of logstash but none of the provide metrics suits.

 PS: I used a kubernetes cluster to deploy my applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metrics provided by [logstash in the API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/node-stats-api.html#pipeline-stats) are not enough for a consistent alerting.

The alternatives can be:

- use [mtail](https://github.com/google/mtail) for parsing the logs and increment a counter whenever you get this specific error.
- use a [blackbox exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter) for checking the availability of ES
- find a way to detect a flatline in your log ingestion (logstash reports events in output which are inconsistent with ES input) - this depends on your setup

Comment: The availability of prometheus is not the concern in my case so i exclude the second option. I will take a look at mtail to see if it can fit  my needs and how i can integrate it in my kubernetes setup.  Google doesn't provide a official image so i will have to build one and run it as a side car on the logstash pod.